# Is it possible to skip a FROM command in a multistage dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Attempting to make a dynamic docker file, where the final image may need one of two previous images based on user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can skip `FROM` command. Build should start from somewhere, even if it is [`scratch`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/#create-a-simple-parent-image-using-scratch).

While for trying to create a dynamic dockerfile, you can create the dockerfile using a shell script. I came across one such script at [parity-deploy.sh](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-deploy/blob/master/parity-deploy.sh), which dynamically creates a `docker-compose.yml` file on the basis of configurations provided by user.

Answer (score 2):

`Dockerfiles` have been able to use `ARGs` to allow passing in parameters during a docker build using the CLI argument --build-arg for some time. But until recently (Docker's 17.05 release, to be precise), you weren't able to use an ARG to specify all or part of your Dockerfile's mandatory FROM command.

But since the pull request [Allow ARG in FROM](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/31352) was merged, you can now specify an image / repository to use at runtime. This is great for flexibility, and as a concrete example, I used this feature to allow me to pull from a private Docker registry when building a Dockerfile in production, or to build from a local Docker image that was created as part of a CI/testing process inside Travis CI.

To use an `ARG` in your `Dockerfile's` FROM:

```
ARG MYAPP_IMAGE=myorg/myapp:latest
FROM $MYAPP_IMAGE
...
```

Then if you want to use a different `image/tag`, you can provide it at runtime:

```
docker build -t container_tag --build-arg MYAPP_IMAGE=localimage:latest .
```

If you don't specify `--build-arg`, then Docker will use the default value in the `ARG`.

Typically, it's preferred that you set the `FROM` value in the Dockerfile itself—but there are many situations (e.g. CI testing) where you can justify making it a runtime argument.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from), you cannot skip it. It should be the first command in the Dockerfile as well.

> As such, a valid Dockerfile must start with a FROM instruction

But notice that:

> FROM can appear multiple times within a single Dockerfile to create multiple images or use one build stage as a dependency for another.

You can edit the file dynamically (e.g. `sed`) to use the image/images that the user has specified.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like docker support now : https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1134